# Use response array in existing ajax call

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am using an array for drop down. I have written a code which is being fired on onchange event for select box. which will replace existing drop down with the new one. And also I am doing some modifications in the existing array. Now every time I want to use new updated array in ajax call.

```
PHP Code - 
$arr = getStudents();
<div id="replace">
<select multiple id="cat" name="cate[]" onchange="myFunction(this.value);">
    <?php foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
    ?> 
            <option id="" value="<?php echo $val['id']; ?>"><?php echo $val['name']; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
</div>

Js Code - 
<script>
function myFunction(id){
        $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url('controller/refresh'); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data:{'ids' : id, 'student' : JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>) },
                success: function( response ) {
                    if(response)
                    {
                      $('#replace').html(response);                     
                    }   
                } //end success
        });//end ajax
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does "use new updated array in ajax call" mean?  Are you trying to send it with each ajax call?  Do you understand that PHP variables are server-side and would only be present in the client if you put them into a Javascript variable that you can then manipulate in the client?  Where's the code that modifies the array?

Comment: Question is not clear at all especially when comparing to the code. Update written description to be very clear exactly what it is you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The controller/refresh must generate on server side the new drop down select html element and to send it back as reponse:

```
<?php
    $response = "<select multiple id=\"cat\" name=\"cate[]\" onchange=\"myFunction(this.value);\">";

    foreach($arr as $key=>$new_val) {
        $response .= "<option id=\"\" value=\"".$new_val['id']."\">".$new_val['name']."</option>";"
    }

    $response .= "</select>";
    print $response;
?>
```

I am don't know how your controller works, but you must output only the above response, otherwise you will end up nesting the whole new page.

Another way is to send as response a json string containing the new options data and to regenerate the selector html on client side.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have solved this issue to create a new view. I am also replacing my ajax function.